# Why wasn't Russia in the Paris Peace Talks?

Tags: world-war-one

After the loss of World War One by Germany and Austria, the Allies convened to discuss in the Paris Peace Talks. It is understandable that Germany and Austria were not allowed to participate in these peace talks. What I don't understand is why Russia wasn't invited to participate. Hadn't they helped the Allies win the war by attacking Germany on the Eastern Front? I understand they were communist, but weren't they a major factor in the victory of World War One?

Comment: Would be interesting to know, did they try to attend? Did they send a delegation?

Comment: According to wikipedia, there was a delegation from a Russian faction present: "Whilst Russia was formally excluded from the Conference,[42] despite having fought the Central Powers for three years, the Russian Provincial Council (chaired by Prince Lvov[43]),the successor to the Russian Constituent Assembly and the political arm of the Russian White movement attended the conference." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Peace_Conference,_1919#All-Russian_Government_.28Whites.29

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Russia made a unilateral peace deal with Germany in 1917 and left the war altogether. And doing so they broke their alliance with the Allies. It would have been strange to see the Allies invite Russia to the peace talk. Also they where in political turmoil and civil war was looming in....

Comment: It would have been strange to see them invite the bolsheviks, but why not invite the whites?

Comment: @Bregalad I am unsure as to when the Allies officially recognized the Bolsheviks, but nonetheless after WWI they had taken over the government, regardless of what the Allies wanted. It wouldn't of made sense to invite a movement that wasn't even part of the government.

Comment: @Bregalad great question! I'd never thought of that. I suppose they didn't think the whites had any hope of delivering on whatever was agreed.

Comment: As I understand, inviting the whites would've been like inviting the ROC to a peace talk instead of the PRC, around the 1970 switchover?

Answer (score 7):

Because the RSFR (I.e. Bolsheviks) weren't recognised as a legal government. In fact both sides of WW1 had been fighting against them. The Bolsheviks refused to pay the Russian Empire's debts or honour its treaties, so really they had no leg to stand on in terms of being recognized as the successor of the Russian Empire, even if they had wanted to be. Since they believed all Europe was about to erupt into revolution, they probably weren't bothered.

Comment: This is not quite true. They were recognized de facto. There was a German ambassador in Moscow (Mirbach, who was assassinated in 1918), and neither the Germans nor the Entente really fought the Bolshevik government, though they helped to some whites in some periods.

Comment: America alone sent over 11,000 troops, and wasn't even the biggest contributor. They directly engaged the Red Army. Britain was the first country to give formal diplomatic recognition to the Soviets, and that wasn't until 1921. At the time of the Paris peace treaties, Russia was still in flux and it wasn't even certain that the Bolsheviks would win.

Comment: Americans engaged the Red Army?? Where did you read this?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Russia_Intervention

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_Bear_Expedition

Comment: If you read your reference CAREFULLY, you will see that there was no real fighting, neither it was intended from the very beginning. You can also conclude that the author of this article tries hard to prove that there was fighting but fails. He does not even mention the main goal of the US part of the expedition: to secure the Russian far East against the Japanese.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would consider real fighting. 144 members of the Polar Bear expedition died, 305 were wounded. The campaign lasted for several months. In any event, the question asked why the Russians weren't invited to the talks. The answer is that the allies were engaged in a military conflict with them. It wasn't called a war because they didn't recognise the Soviets as Russia's government.

Comment: As I said this article is biased. They don't say explicitly who killed these 144 dead. There was no real organized fighting between Americans and the Red Army.

Comment: And there was no Red Army units in the far east at that time. As soon as they arrived Americans left. Their mission was complete. They prevented the Japanese takeover of the Russian far East.

Comment: Well, who killed them then? It says they were combat deaths, not disease or accident. And their enemy was the Red Army, no one else. I'm not sure what bias would make someone want to big up this campaign, which after all was a dismal failure.

Comment: No, this article is about the area around archangel. I know you're the Russian here, but that ain't in the far east.

Comment: There was no US troops near Archangel. There were British troops. And their purpose was to protect the Entente military stores from the Germans. They also did not really fight the Red Army. They withdrew after German surrender.

Comment: "The Polar Bear Expedition (also known as the Northern Russian Expedition, the American North Russia Expeditionary Force - ANREF or the American Expeditionary Force North Russia - AEFNR) was a contingent of about 5,000 United States Army troops[1] that landed in Arkhangelsk, Russia as part of the Allied intervention". That's the beginning of the article I linked. The 5000 Americans claim is cited to a book. I haven't read it of course, but I think it's not for me to prove the book is accurate.

Comment: Have you read it carefully? ;)